# Is every conformal transformation given by a conformal Killing field?

Tags: differential-geometry, conformal-geometry

I am reading *A Mathematical Introduction to Conformal Field Theory, Second Edition* by Schottenloher. In the first chapter, he classifies the conformal transformations on $\Bbb R^{p,q}$ by classifying those transformations that arise as the flows of conformal Killing fields. He states that

> Every conformal transformation $\varphi$ on a connected open subset of $\Bbb R ^{p,q}$ which is an element $\varphi = \varphi_{t_0}$
> of a one-parameter group $(\varphi_t)$ of conformal transformations, is a composition of maps of the form
> $$
> q \mapsto \left\{q + c, \Lambda q \ (\text{with } \Lambda \in O(p,q)), e^\lambda q, \frac{q - \langle q, q\rangle b}{1 - 2 \langle q, b\rangle + \langle q, q \rangle \langle b, b \rangle}\right\}.
> $$

Now, I know that all sufficiently smooth conformal transformations are of this form, so I am  wondering if there is a way to derive the more general classification (all sufficiently smooth conformal transformations) from that for the transformations that arise as flows of conformal Killing fields.

On the Wikipedia page for conformal groups it states that all conformal groups are Lie groups. I wonder if using the fundamental vector field, I can show that all the elements of the conformal group are given by conformal Killing fields. I imagine these results are probably in some introductory textbook, but I am not sure where to look. Can anybody recommend a comprehensive reference?

Comment: There are Riemannian manifolds with finite nontrivial conformal group. Hence, none of these conformal transformations can come from conformal Killing fields. Are you assuming connected conformal group? What signature are you interested in?

Comment: Also, in the signature (1,1) case, the conformal group is much larger than the one written: it is not a Lie group in this case.

Comment: The key clause is "every conformal transformation *which is an element of a one parameter group*" without this caveat it may not be possible to generate a particular transformation using conformal killing fields. Reflections in $\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$ are a simple counterexample to this.

Comment: @Kajelad I understand, but the author states a theorem claiming that *every* conformal transformation is of that form, and he does comment immediately after the paragraph I quoted that the general case can be deduced from the one-parameter group one. How does one deduce the general case, at least for $\Bbb R ^{p,q}$ with $p+q>2$?

Comment: @MoisheKhan from the reading I got the feeling that finding the conformal group from the transformations generated by conformal Killing fields was a standard argument, but your comments tell me I was wrong. Schottenloher claims that it is possible to go from the statement I quoted to the general case (all conformal transformations on $\Bbb R^{p,q}$ with $p+q>2$), but I do not see a way to prove this claim. How does one close the gap, at least for $\Bbb R^{p,q}$ with $p+q>2$?

Comment: @GuachoPerez You should spell my name correctly when you ping me. Mistakes like this, sadly, are very common in physics literature, you should not always trust math statements that you find there. Try to revise the question to make things clearer, I am still unsure what are you asking.

Comment: @MoisheKohan If $G$ is the conformal group of $M$, let $G ^*$ consist of those $g \in G$ for which there exists a vector field $X$ on $M$ s.t. $g = \phi_t ^X$ for some real $t$ (where $\phi^X$ denotes the flow of $X$). All elements of $G^*$ can be found by: (1) Solving a conformal Killing equation $\mathcal L_X g = \lambda g$ for $X$, and (2) integrating $X$ to find $\phi ^X$. This is a systematic way to find $G ^*$. My question is under which conditions on $M$ or $G$ can we ensure that $G ^* = G$? In such situations, we would have a systematic way of finding $G$, which is my main interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and let $G$ be the group of conformal diffeomorphisms from $M$ onto
itself. Assume $G$ is a connected Lie group. Any $X \in \frak{g} = \text{Lie}(G)$ generates a one-parameter
subgroup of $G$ given by $\phi_t = \exp(t X)$. Denote the action of $\phi_t$ on $M$ by $p \cdot
\phi_t$. Because $\phi_t$ is a one-parameter group in $G$, the map $p \mapsto p \cdot \phi_t$ defines a global
flow on $M$ with infinitesimal generator $\hat X$. We want to show that $\hat X$ is a conformal Killing vector
field.
\begin{align*}
  (\mathcal L_{\hat X} g)_p(Y, Z) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \left( (\phi_h ^*g)_p(Y, Z) - g_p(Y, Z) \right)
  \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \left( \lambda_h(p) g_p(Y, Z) - g_p(Y, Z)
                                      \right)
  \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \left( \lambda_h(p) - 1
       \right) g_p(Y, Z) = \frac{\text d }{\text d t} \Big|_{t = 0} \lambda_t(p)
       g_p(Y, Z)
\end{align*}
In particular, if we let $\kappa(p) =  \frac{1}{2}\frac{\text d }{\text d t} \Big|_{t = 0} \lambda_t(p)$, and expand the
Lie derivative in terms of the Levi-Civita connection to get
\begin{equation}
 \text{Sym}(\nabla \hat X ^{\flat}) = \kappa g. \label{eq:conf-killing-eq}
\end{equation}
Solving this system of linear, first order partial differential equations for $\hat X$ and then constructing
its flow furnishes every $1$-parameter subgroup of $G$. If $G ^*$ is the subgroup generated by all
$1$-parameter subgroups, then $G ^*$ is path-connected because each of its points can be reached from the
identity by following a finite sequence of flows. It follows that $\bar{G ^*}$ is also connected, and by
Cartan's theorem it is a Lie subgroup of $G$ which contains all of its $1$-parameter subgroups, whence
$\text{Lie}(G) = \text{Lie}(\bar{G ^*}) \Rightarrow G = \bar{G ^*}$ by the Lie Correspondence (Theorem 20.21
in Lee SM). We have hence shown that when $\text{Conf}(M)$ is a connected Lie group, then all conformal
transformations of $M$ can be found by solving the conformal Killing equation